# Eevee linear / cubic volume interpolation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I am trying to render VDB-clouds. In cycles I have the option to chose the interpolation in the material properties. With linear interpolation the clouds look jagged/blocky. With cubic they look smooth. In eevee I am not able to find this option. Am I missing something?

Cycles linear interpolation:
[image: cycles linear interpolation]

Cycles cubic interpolation:
[image: cycles cubic interpolation]

Eevee render (I assume linear interpolation):
[image: eevee render]

The setting in the material properties using cycles:
[image]